# Joining 3 tables with a common column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with a common column and I'm trying to create a view where the 3 tables are merged using the id column.

Here is what I've tried so far. It has an error that I can't figure out how to fix (error is said to occur on the 'from airline a' line):

```
Create view ‘Runway_crew’ as
    Select a.airline_id, a.craft_model,
           m.airline_id, m.engine_check, m.fuel_check, m.flight_controls, m.windows_and_doors, m.head_mechanic, m.head_engineer, m.craft_status,
           f.airline_id, f.departure_datetime, f.runway
    From airline a
    Join      flight f      On f.airline_id = a.airline_id
    Left join maintenance m On a.airline_id = m.airline_id;
```

I'm now getting a 'duplicate column id' error

Comment: can you share samples from the three tables and the expected output?

Comment: remove the last comma in this: `f.departure_datetime, f.runway,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`, use `INNER JOIN` and remove the duplicated column `airline_id`:

```
Create view ‘Runway_crew’ as
    SELECT a.airline_id, a.craft_model,
           m.engine_check, m.fuel_check, m.flight_controls, m.windows_and_doors, m.head_mechanic, m.head_engineer, m.craft_status,
           f.departure_datetime, f.runway
    FROM airline a
    INNER JOIN flight f ON f.airline_id = a.airline_id
    INNER JOIN maintenance m ON a.airline_id = m.airline_id;
```